# Rename a file case in JFS, case insensitive

Tags: jfs, case-insensitive

I working on a JFS filsystem made with the option -O (case insensitive filenames).

How can I easily rename a file from Test.txt to test.txt ?

Using mv report the error:

```
mv: ‘Test.txt’ and ‘test.txt’ are the same file
```

And nautilus reports

```
The name “test.txt” is already used in this location. Please use a different name.
```

Now I can rename it to Test2.txt followed by renaming to test.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rename` command.

It's not actually a built-in shell command, like `mv`, but a pearl script that comes by default with most GNU/Linux distros. It's usage is a bit different from `mv` because it uses Pearl regular expressions to compare against a list of files.

Here's how to use it in your case:

`rename 's/Test\.txt/test\.txt/' *`

The `s` tells the `rename` command to search and replace all occurrences of *Test.txt* with *test.txt*. The dots `.` inside the regular expression must be escaped with a `\`, that's why the filenames are written like `Test\.txt`. Notice the `*` at the end of the command, that means to look through all files in the current directory.

You can pass the `-n` option to the `rename` command if you want to test it without making any changes.

Comment: sorry did not work, same type of error message: .... already exists.

Comment: What about this: `rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *`? Note that it will try to rename all files in the current directory to lower case. If none of these options work I'll remove my answer.

Comment: Same error, I assume after the magic is done the end result is still something equivalent to 'mv'.
You can remove the answer later if there is a solution, I fear that if you remove it too soon someone else might write a new similar one.

Comment: I presume the correct answer is what you already figured out then: rename to something else and then back to the wanted name.